# Dart / Flutter : Waiting for a loop to be completed before continuing... (Async Await?)

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function which creates a sublist from a large(very large list). After creating this list, the function goes on treating it (deleting duplicates, sorting...).

As long as the list was not too big, it worked fine. But now, I get "The Getter length was called on null". I suppose, it's because the second part of the function (after the loop) starts before the sublist is completed... so it doesn't work...

How can we force the function to wait for the loop to be over to continue the rest of the treatment ?
Is it with Async /Await ? Or can we do something like "While... something is not over...", or "As soon as something is done... do that" ? (My suggestions might be naive, but I am a beginner...)

Here is the code :

```
List themeBankFr() {
  List<Map> themeBankFr = [];
  for (Word word in wordBank) {
    for (Thematique wordTheme in word.theme) {
      themeBankFr.add({
        'themeFr': wordTheme.themeFr,
        'image': wordTheme.image,
      });
    }
  }
// convert each item to a string by using JSON encoding
  final jsonList = themeBankFr.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();

  // using toSet - toList strategy
  final uniqueJsonList = jsonList.toSet().toList();

  // convert each item back to the original form using JSON decoding
  final result = uniqueJsonList.map((item) => jsonDecode(item)).toList();

  // sort the list of map in alphabetical order
  result.sort((m1, m2) {
    var r = m1['themeFr'].compareTo(m2['themeFr']);
    if (r != 0) return r;
    return m1['image'].compareTo(m2['image']);
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: *"But now, I get "The Getter length was called on null"."* - where is it? what is the stacktrace?

Comment: The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was
MyHomePage
lib\screens\starting_page.dart:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _StringBase.compareTo (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:297:29)
#2      themeBankFr.<anonymous closure>
package:words_words/widgets/list_maker.dart:30
#3      Sort._insertionSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:69:36)
#4      Sort._doSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:58:7)

Comment: It's just the opening page which routes to "My Home Page" : just a background image

Comment: As long as you don't use a `Future<>` or call an API (or web service) you don't need to handle async. Your error might be in another place. Can you share the code where you get the length ?

Comment: When my list (wordBank) contains about 30 items, it works fine. When I add about 150, it crashes. When I delete the second part of my function "ThemeBankFr", it works again. So i concluded it must come from there. I never really call length. It must be in the "sorting" part of the function...

Comment: Can you check that m1 and m2 (and in particulary their attributs themeFr and image) are not null when you sort them ?

Comment: Yes, I am going to check my wordBank again.

Comment: I found the bug... So sorry. I should have looked more carefully in the bank before. I am still wondering about my function : what if the list was really huge : 15,000 word objects, or 20000, could it create a problem as the loop would take too long to complete, and so the rest of the function wouldn't work ?

Comment: Glad to hear !
It's not a problem to process a huge amount of data, you won't get a bug to this as long as it's synchrone. The real problem is : does the user have to wait for the data to be processed ? If it does, you should use an async method and display a loading spinner to the user.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it will always "wait" for the loop to be over before trying to do "jsonlist=themeBankFr.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();" ?

Comment: Exactly, as long as you don't use the `async` or `Future` words, it will be synchrone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think i have a good answer that may helps you and it will as following

first create another function to do the work of for loops and this function returns a future of list that you need like below

```
Future<List<Map>> futureList(List wordBank){
  List<Map> themeBankFr = [];
  for (Word word in wordBank) {
    for (Thematique wordTheme in word.theme) {
      themeBankFr.add({
        'themeFr': wordTheme.themeFr,
        'image': wordTheme.image,
      });
    }
  }
  return Future.value(themeBankFr);
}
```

after that you can use this function inside your code and use it as async await and now you will never run the below lines before you return this array like below

```
List themeBankFr() async {
  List<Map> themeBankFr = await futureList(wordBank);
// convert each item to a string by using JSON encoding
  final jsonList = themeBankFr.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();

  // using toSet - toList strategy
  final uniqueJsonList = jsonList.toSet().toList();

  // convert each item back to the original form using JSON decoding
  final result = uniqueJsonList.map((item) => jsonDecode(item)).toList();

  // sort the list of map in alphabetical order
  result.sort((m1, m2) {
    var r = m1['themeFr'].compareTo(m2['themeFr']);
    if (r != 0) return r;
    return m1['image'].compareTo(m2['image']);
  });

  return result;
}
```

i think this will solve your problem and i hope this useful for you

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. I will try it out :)Thanks alot.